# How can I add an object into vector?

Tags: java, object, vector, addition

The question is-
Given the details of flights as input, create a `vector` of the object `Ticket`. Note that the tickets should appear in the `vector` in the same order as the input.
The details have been provided as a `String[]`. Each item in the array corresponds to a ticket and has the following space separated details: `Origin, destination, departure, arrival, amount`.

I tried following and since I am a newbie and I am doing this for the first time I am unable to find my way.

```
   import java.util.Vector;

    public class FlightTickets {

        String origin;
        String destination;
        String departure;
        String arrival;
        String amount;
        Vector v = new Vector();

        public FlightTickets(String origin, String destination, String departure, String arrival, String amount) {
            this.origin = origin;
            this.destination = destination;
            this.departure = departure;
            this.arrival = arrival;
            this.amount = amount;
        }

        public static void main(String[] args) {
            FlightTickets ticket = new FlightTickets("Caledonia", "South Korea", "10:00", "5:00", "15000");
            v.add(ticket);
        }
    }
```

Comment: `v` is an *instance* variable, but you're trying to use it from a `static` method. You should read http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html which will explain why that's a problem.

Comment: Also, use Java naming conventions for your identifiers. `Origin` should be `origin`l for example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {           
    FlightTickets ticket = new FlightTickets("Caledonia", "South <bKorea", "10:00", "5:00", "15000");
    ticket.v.add(ticket);
}
```

Remember that you cannot access a non-static variable from a static method.
BTW, as the Vector class is a generic type it's better to define 'v' like this :

```
Vector<TestClass> v = new Vector<TestClass>();
```

---

As a response to your comment I provide a rather complete implementation for more details:

```
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Vector;

public class TestClass {

    String Origin;
    String destination;
    String departure;
    String arrival;
    String amount;
    Vector<TestClass> v = new Vector<TestClass>();

    public TestClass(String Origin, String destination, String departure, String arrival, String amount) {
        this.Origin = Origin;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.departure = departure;
        this.arrival = arrival;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        TestClass ticket = new TestClass("Caledonia", "South Korea", "10:00", "5:00", "15000");
        ticket.v.add(ticket);
        Iterator<TestClass> it = ticket.v.iterator();
        while(it.hasNext())
            System.out.println(it.next().Origin);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help and I tried every solution but no one is giving me a output.I think may be something else is also wrong in the code

Comment: I dont know why but it is giving error of removing argument type from iterator.

Comment: 1)what's the error?2)which argument and where? (do u mean Origin?)

Comment: In this statement-Iterator<TestClass> it = ticket.v.iterator();  It is saying to remove Testclass.

Comment: Did you copy and pasted my code in a file named TestClass.java or not?

Comment: Since my filename is FlightTickets.java so I replaced TestClass with FlightTickets at every place in your code.

Comment: That's ok, so if you've made this change in this line 'Iterator<TestClass> it = ticket.v.iterator()' too, you should not encounter an error.BTW, you can remeve <FlightTickets> from every where, and just get a warning. But just use the it this way: System.out.println( ((FlightTickets)it.next()).Origin );

Comment: I did as you said and saved your code in a file named TestClass.java and now it is not giving error but it is adding only only one information of ticket.I tried adding others but it didnt work.can you tell me how to add others?

Comment: Indeed you should change lots of things in your program.It's better to make a Vector of TestClass inside the main method (not in your class) and in a loop add a new instance of TestClass to the Vector.

Comment: Thanks for the help.Now I know what I have to do.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot acccess the Member variables of FlightTickets inside a static function(including main) without using the object of FlightTickets.

You should do the following :

```
f.v.add(ticket);
```

This is not a standard practice and many programmers use other techniques by abstracting the data structure being used internally. You can create a funcction in FlightTickets as below  :

```
public void addTickets(FlightTicket ticket)
{
    this.v.add(ticket);
}
```

Also the class that you have designed is confusing as FlightTicket has a vector in which you are storing collection of FlightTickets. Probably you might want to think about designing it in a better way.

Answer (score 0):

A simple fix is to move `Vector v = new Vector();` inside the main method. This results in:

```
import java.util.Vector;
public class FlightTickets {
    String origin;
    String destination;
    String departure;
    String arrival;
    String amount;

    public FlightTickets(String origin, String destination, String departure, String arrival, String amount){
        this.origin = origin;
        this.destination = destination;
        this.departure = departure;
        this.arrival = arrival;
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){
        FlightTickets ticket = new FlightTickets("Caledonia", "South Korea", "10:00", "5:00", "15000");
        Vector v = new Vector();
        v.add(ticket);
    }
}
```

As mentioned in the comments by @obicere you are better off using [ArrayList](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html) or [List](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/List.html). The real reason the code does not work is as answered by @kakarot, you cannot access non-static fields from static methods.

Comment: Thanks and I tried this but this is giving no output.I think there might be some other error also.

Comment: Off course there is no output; nothing is ever printed! If you want to do that use `System.out.println(v)` (depending on what you want to print)